# c# How to get the file path from 'Open With'?

Tags: c#, file, process, path, pathname

I'm making a text editor and I'm trying to make a code to get the file path of a file when it's open in a application using 'Open With'.

**Details**: 'Open With' is an option when you right click on a file. The file then becomes a shortcut to the application. I have tried to use `Process` , but I couldn't seem to get the path from a file process.

**Question**: In c#, how do you get the file path of a file when using 'Open With'?

[image: Example of 'Open With']

**EDIT**:
Application path is C:\Users\Mayhem\Documents

Text file path is   C:\Users\Mayhem\Desktop

I need to get the file path of 'text file'.

[image: Example of a file that's using 'Open With']

Comment: Hello John, not sure what you want to achieve in C#. When you click on "Open With", apart from the default applications, you get an option to "choose default program". Using this you can locate your app and bind file extension to open with your app always.

Comment: I'm not sure either, do you want the default program path for a file or extension?

Comment: Very unclear what you want... Obviously if it is your program launched as in the end you just get file name as first argument - so you probably asking about something else. Maybe you are looking how that "open with" list is populated and get list of paths to executables?

Comment: @Anand my goal is to open a file in the application using the path from 'Open With'. With that, I need to make a code that gets the path.

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov Any file path that I try to get is from the application path. I need the path from where it's opened using 'Open With'.

Comment: Can you please repeat that comment, but avoid "it" and "path" - instead for each occurrence add something like "path to file (example.ff in this case)" or "path to my executable"... Note that generally your code does not run at all while user selects program - only when finally opening the file your program will be launched with file path as argument (but again, it is unlikely you are looking for help with that last step as path is right there in program's first argument)

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov I see, `Process getFilePath = new Process();` would probably be the only way to get the file path before the file opens in the application (exe).. Can you show me an example on how to get the file path using `Process` ?

Answer (score 2):

My goal is to get the path of a file using 'Open With'.
This code shows all paths opened with the application, including the file path.

```
string[] openedPaths = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `using System;`

```
string filePath;
string[] paths = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

if (paths.Length > 1)
{
    filePath = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[1];
}

if (filePath != null)
{
    //Do your staff
}
```

filePath will be path of file you opened with your application.